# flower segmentation using GrabCut in OpenCv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to create a model for flower segmentation. I want to train model with many images. I want to use GrabCut in opencv. I have read this [link](http://www.packtpub.com/article/opencv-segmenting-images). but this only uses one image for segmentation. how can I use GrabCut for the above mentioned purpose?

here is some sample from flower's pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From the link you mentioned: "The cv::grabCut function is easy to use. You just need to input an image and label some of its pixels as belonging to the background or to the foreground. Based on this partial labeling, the algorithm will then determine a foreground/background segmentation for the complete image."

Comment: "The two internal models maintained by the algorithm are passed as argument of the function (and returned) such that it is possible to call the function with the models of the last run again if one wishes to improve the segmentation result by performing additional iterations"

Answer (score 2):

If all the images are like the ones shown, and you are set on using grabcut, then you can cheat by setting a mask to the central pixels and then using grabcut with the mask option.

If all the images are like the ones shown, and you are not set on using grabcut, then maybe try salient segmentation, it seems to like flowers.

http://mmcheng.net/salobj/

If you want a general "model" that can segment flowers that is much more difficult.   Perhaps check my other post https://stackoverflow.com/a/24624938/3669776 for some bedtime reading :)